# Python closure memory management

Tags: python

When I run this code

```
def outer():
    xs = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
    print(xs)
    print(id(xs))
    xid = id(xs)
    def inner():
        xs = {1,2,3,4}
        print(xs)
        print(id(xs))
        yid = id(xs)
        print(xid == yid)
    return inner


fn = outer()
fn()
```

xid and yid value is the same in intellij,

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
140317084319328
{1, 2, 3, 4}
140317084319328
True
```

but when i run in a terminal

```
>>> fn = outer()
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
140343083023728
>>> fn()
{1, 2, 3, 4}
140343082597504
```

they are different. I am expecting that yid should be different because there is no interning happening for a list. Can anyone explain this behaviour

Comment: TL;DR: *implementation details.* The set does go out of scope after `outer` is done, so its memory location *can* be reclaimed, but *does not have to*. For some reason or another, Python internally reuses the memory location in one case but not in a very different situation. You'll have to dig through the implementation details if you really want to figure out why, but I'm not sure what that exercise would be useful for.

Comment: @deceze, I agree with your answer. but that link that was shared, does not answer this question.